# Bash grep -r -H showing without waiting till process end

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I want to search by specify string that contains on all files recursively

I've try with

```
grep -r -H "String to search" /var/www/vhosts/domain.com
```

it's working fine and don't need long time to search

but when I try to grep on vhosts dir

```
grep -r -H "String to search" /var/www/vhosts/
```

It was need long time cause so many domains there (about some thousands), here I want to print the result though search onprocess

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: What do you mean by "print the result though search onprocess"? `grep` already does print matches as they are found.

Comment: @kaylum, yes , BUT process search must be end then grep giving output to terminal ... i want though still search it's always print the output as like looping

Comment: It does that already. It's not printing because it hasn't found anything yet.

Comment: @kaylum, Ooohh .... so how to print which dir that current scan ?I want to know where the current scan process

Comment: `grep` doesn't have that capability. If you want a running progress then you will need to write your own wrapper script.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want `-c` may be useful. That doesn't print the matched lines but prints a count of matches for each file. Which will include files that don't match.